# Modality between mfc and hosted wpf

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, mfc

I am hosting a WPF window inside an MFC application.  I'm using WindowInteropHelper to set the Owner of the WPF window to the app's main MFC window.  The problem is when I try to create and show a modal dialog box in the main app with CDialog::DoModal, it's only modal for the MFC window.

Interestingly, MessageBox has a MB_TASKMODAL style that works with the WPF window perfectly, but I can't find anything like it for CDialog.

I currently have a workaround that gets the handle to the WPF window through the WindowInteropHelper and sets that as the dialog's parent, and then manually disables and re-enables the MFC window before and after calling DoModal, but it's an ugly hack.

Has anybody else encountered this type of hosted WPF problem before?